# umbraco 7: attach pdf from tinyMCE

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I would like to ask, is it possible for me to select pdf from the tinyMCE media picker?
I couldn't find any solution on this.
Appreciate if someone can advise me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with the media picker, but you can do it with Link, and then select "Link to file".

[image]

Comment: Nvr thought of that. Thanks ^^